# Cyclic subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering if I have the following definition understood; cyclic subgroup. Suppose we take Z_8. This set is {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}. Then 1,3,5,7 generate the group. But 0,2,4,6 do not. But are those cyclic subgroups?

Comment: Well, first of all, are those subgroups?

Comment: Yeah. @Cameron Buie

Comment: Well, no. They aren't. They are *elements* of the group.

Comment: Uh yeah they are.

Comment: What are the elements of $6,$ for example?

Comment: I just did not use the notation like <1>,<2>,...

Comment: Aha! Now *that* makes sense.

Comment: As a side note, notation is important. It helps people understand what you're talking about in less space than it would take to spell it all out in words.

Answer (score 0):

In a finite group, a cyclic subgroup is just one which is created by starting with one element and applying the operation repeatedly until you stop getting any new elements.  In the case of $\Bbb Z_8$ with the operation of addition, you could start with $1$ to get the cyclic subgroup
$$\eqalign{\langle1\rangle
  &=\{1,\,1+1,\,1+1+1,\,\ldots\}\cr
  &=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3,\ldots\}\cr
  &=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\cr
  &={\Bbb Z}_8\ .\cr}$$
If you start with $3$ you get the same:
$$\eqalign{\langle3\rangle
  &=\{3,\,3+3,\,3+3+3,\,\ldots\}\cr
  &=\{3,6,1,4,7,2,5,0,3,6,1,\ldots\}\cr
  &=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\cr
  &={\Bbb Z}_8\ .\cr}$$
On the other hand,  if you start with $6$ you get
$$\eqalign{\langle6\rangle
  &=\{6,4,2,0,6,4,2,\ldots\}\cr
  &=\{0,2,4,6\}\cr
  &\ne{\Bbb Z}_8\ .\cr}$$
Note that when you say $1,3,5,7$ generate the group, you probably mean that each of them separately generates the group.  It is also true that the four elements together generate the group, but this is a slightly different question.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, given any element $x$ of a group $G,$ $\langle x\rangle$ is the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ that contain $x.$ It is fairly straightforward to show that any such subgroup contains all "integer multiples" of $x$ (assuming an additive group), and that the set of all "integer multiples" of $x$ is a subgroup of $G.$ Thus, $\langle x\rangle$ is precisely the set of "integer multiples" of $x,$ so is a cyclic (sub)group (of $G$) generated by $x$.